# How should I register event handlers to a video that is handled by the videojs?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to register an event handler to a video that is handled by the videojs but I can`t select the element in a reliable manner because the videojs removes the attributes from the video tag and add them to a container element that it adds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*videojs* seems to append the same suffix: `_html5_api` to every video element ID,  when it is wrapped inside the container div. Quoting from the [source](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/player.js#L270):

> // Update tag id/class for use as HTML5 playback tech
>
> // Might think we should do this after embedding in container so .vjs-tech class
>
> // doesn't flash 100% width/height, but class only applies with .video-js parent
>
> ```
> tag.id += '_html5_api';
> ```

So, one would argue that, a ***trivial*** fix would be something like this:

`var vid = document.getElementById("ORIGINALVIDEOID_html5_api")`

Of course, this hack lacks reliability since this suffix might change in future versions. However, one thing that is unlikely to be changed in the future, is the presence of the `video` element (albeit with a different ID) inside the wrapper div.

So, a more **reliable** way to obtain the video element *per se* is (assuming that the video tag ID is *"cool"*):

```
videojs("cool").ready(function(){
    // Approach 1
    var video1 = this.contentEl().querySelector("video");
    console.log("video1");
    console.log(video1);
    // Approach 2
    var video_id = this.contentEl().querySelector("video").getAttribute("id");
    var video2 = document.getElementById(video_id);
    console.log("video2");
    console.log(video2);
    // Not really needed, but here is a test that both approaches yield the same result
    console.log("video1 === video2 ?")
    console.log(video1===video2)
})
```

which yields in Firefox:

[image]

I included two approaches in the above script: one straightforward and one indirect (via the document and using the acquired ID). Of course you can use whichever of `video1` and `video2` you want.

---

A few things to note here:

- This works only when inside a `videojs().ready()` function; this is a way to be 100% sure that the player is loaded
- `contentEl()` returns the wrapper div and then, `querySelector()` is used on it to access the video element.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are trying to get a video element within the player but this is flawed as the player tech can be something other than a video element, e.g. the Flash tech. You should use the video.js API to listen to the events which will be surfaced from the tech.

```
var player = videojs("id");
player.on('play', function() {…});
```

Comment: -1:How does this answer the question? First, it doesn't provide a reference to the video element _per se_, which is _exactly_ what the OP wants. How do _you_ know what kind of events the OP needs to handle? Or when? Second, whatever it does, it does it _only_ when the video is played.Third, there is no specific mention of `flash` videos in the question; your being "general" ended up in missing OP's immediate issues. Next time, before downvoting without a comment(after the answer is accepted),take a minute for some self-reflection:"Does MY OWN answer address the issues raised by the question?"